# Conditional logic, WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I got two different pages in my WordPress theme.

front-page.php (home page) and blog.php (secondary page)

I'm trying to use two different menus depending on which page you are visiting.

To do this I use conditional logic in WordPress.

```
<?php if (is_page('52')) {  ?> 
                    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=64" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink; btn">Nyheter</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <a href="#akontakt" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink; btn"> Kontakt</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                    <a href="#arestaurang" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink; btn"> Restaurang</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                   <a href="#abowling" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink; btn">  Bowling</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                  <a href="#aarrangemang" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink; btn"> Arrangemang</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                   <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink; btn">  Hem</a>
                   <?php  } ?>
                   <?php if (is_page(64)) {  ?><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink; btn">  Hem</a><?php  } ?>
```

The page with the ID of 64 (blog) works as it should. But I'm having trouble with the page ID of 52 (front-page.php).
It seems that I can't find the true name of it. The menu is not called for whatever reason when you are visiting the front page.

I have tried to use a different name like, 'front-page.php'. But still, no menu. This is how the url looks like on the front page: http://localhost/wordpress/

I need more ideas on how to find the name of this certain page.

Comment: You can try [is_front_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) condition

Comment: Note that we can't access your localhost.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I just wanted to point out that the option to check the URL is not available.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Thanks man! I had no idea what to search for but now the conditional logic works fine.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you have a **lot** of syntax issues, are using multiple identical IDs, and (for some reason) aren't using the menu functions provided by WordPress...Those aren't contributing to this issue, but may cause others. Just a friendly heads-up.

Comment: I will clean up the code when I have done a bit more progress in the project. But thanks for the heads-up Mevius. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write this line as:-

```
<?php if (is_page(52)) {  ?>
```

you can also try

```
if (is_page( 'Page Title' ) )
```

This [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) will help you.

Comment: @Michael: Okay brother.